# ZeroClipboard works in one IE page but not works in another

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, zeroclipboard

I am using ZeroClipboard to copy link text to clipoboard by clicking on image button in MVC applicaition. On First page

HTML

```
<a  id="pubLink" href="SomeLink" target="_blank">SomeLink</a>
<button id="copy-button" data-clipboard-target="pubLink" class="image-button"></button>
```

javascript

```
var clip = new ZeroClipboard(document.getElementById("copy-button"), {
                moviePath:Url + "/Content/swf/ZeroClipboard.swf"
            });

clip.on('load', function (client)
{
 alert( "movie is loaded" );
});
```

The same markup and javascript loaded on another page - Two.cshtml.

But when i am trying to copy link text in page Two.cshtml page hangs for some time and then I get many javascript errors about stack overflow:

```
SCRIPT28: Out of stack space 
jquery-1.8.2.js, line 4027 character 2
SCRIPT2343: Stack overflow at line: 4027
```

and

```
jquery-1.8.2.js, line 2282 character 4
SCRIPT2343: Stack overflow at line: 2282 
SCRIPT28: Out of stack space
```

This two page works fime on Crome and FF, but not page Two.cshtml in IE9
Maybe anyone already solve that problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Few minutes ago I am tried to play with markup and understand that I need to tell some more detail. In project I am using bootstrap library for popup windows. On page Two.cshtml I reder partial view PublikLink.cshtml which shown in popup - and here button to copy link text. Important that javascript error occurs when I am using Zeroclipboard on popup window murkup. When for test purposes I am copied copy button with link to main Two.cshtml markup - it works fine.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem?